# Unquoted spaces using DelimitedClassBuilder with FileHelpers

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I'm struggling with something that I'm not sure is due to a bug or incomplete object set up & properties.

I'm using FileHelpers to process a CSV file.

If I use inline attributes to process the data as below all is fine;

```
[IgnoreFirst(1)]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Job
{
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.AllowForBoth)]
    public string WM_Identifier;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.AllowForBoth)]
    public string JobDesription;
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")]
    public DateTime? Job_Start_Date_Time;
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")]
    public DateTime? Job_End_Date_Time;
}
```

processed with

```
        FileHelperEngine<Job> engine = new FileHelperEngine<Job>();
        engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.ThrowException;
        engine.SetProgressHandler(ProgressChangeHandler, ProgressMode.NotifyRecords);

        _parsedJobs = engine.ReadFile(dlgOpen.FileName) as Job[];
```

Here's a data sample;

"OGEA03181733",new build,05/11/2012 13:00:00,05/11/2012 17:00:00

However the date format is not known until runtime (** I've hard coded format in code below for illustrative purposes) so I have used the DelimitedClassBuilder as follows

```
public class Job
{
    public string WM_Identifier;
    public string JobDesription;
    public DateTime? Job_Start_Date_Time;
    public DateTime? Job_End_Date_Time;
}

        DelimitedClassBuilder cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("Job", ",");
        cb.IgnoreEmptyLines = true;
        cb.IgnoreFirstLines = 1;

        string[] ClassBuilderFields1 = {"WM_Identifier","JobDescription"};
        foreach (string myFieldName in ClassBuilderFields1)
        {
            cb.AddField(myFieldName, typeof(String));
            cb.LastField.QuoteMode = QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth;
            cb.LastField.QuoteMultiline = MultilineMode.AllowForBoth;
        }

        string dataDateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //**
        string dataTimeFormat = "HH:mm:ss"; //**

        string[] variableDateTimeFields = { "Job_Start_Date_Time", "Job_End_Date_Time"};

        foreach (string myFieldName in variableDateTimeFields)
        {
            cb.AddField(myFieldName, typeof(DateTime));
            cb.LastField.FieldNullValue = DateTime.Today;
            cb.LastField.Converter.Kind = ConverterKind.Date;
            cb.LastField.Converter.Arg1 = string.Format("{0} {1}", dataDateFormat, dataTimeFormat);
        }
```

When I now process I get the following error

The delimiter ',' can´t be found after the field 'JobDescription' at line 2 (the record has less fields, the delimiter is wrong or the next field must be marked as optional

If I place the jobdescription in quotes it processes fine with the class builder but the data is supplied by a customer so I have no control (hence the date format problem!!). I checked the properties of the engine in both cases but can't find a discrepency. The inline solution works regardless of whether the job description is quoted or unquoted but the equivelent (as I see it) class builder version will only work if the job description is quoted.

Thanks for any help. I Feel FileHelpers is a great asset so would prefer to persist with this approach if an answer can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem in the ClassBuilder, I will be creating the test case and try to solve issue, but in the meanwhile I strong recomend you to use this approach:

Read the Date fields as string and later process them at run time with the correct format:

```
[IgnoreFirst(1)]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Job
{
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.AllowForBoth)]
    public string WM_Identifier;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.AllowForBoth)]
    public string JobDesription;

    public string Job_Start_Date_Time;
    public string Job_End_Date_Time;
}
```

Chhers

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the record class with

```
Type dynamicallyCreatedRecordClass = cb.CreateRecordClass();
```

And then you create a (non-generic) engine with the dynamically created class.

```
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(dynamicallyCreatedRecordClass);
```

When you read the file (as in the examples) into a `DataTable` which is one way of getting the data values out. You cannot use `Job[]` because the engine is not based on `Job`, but on `dynamicallyCreatedRecordClass.GetType()`.

```
DataTable _parsedJobs = engine.ReadFileAsDT(dlgOpen.FileName);
```

Comment: `ReadFileAsDT` is ***obsolete*** for _version 3.2_